# Accessing class field in foreach Generics Scala

Tags: scala, generics

I created this code

```
trait Animal {}

class Chien extends Animal {}

class Chat(name:String) extends Animal {
  def this()=this("Chat sans nom")
}

class Siamois(name:String) extends Chat(name:String) {
  def this()=this("Siamois sans nom")
}

class BébéSiamois(name:String) extends Siamois(name:String) {
  def this()=this("Bébé Siamois sans nom")
}

val chat1:Chat=new Chat("Darius") // ne passera pas
val chat2:Siamois=new Siamois("Iroise")
val chat3:BébéSiamois=new BébéSiamois("Jazz")
val chat4:Siamois=new BébéSiamois("Enzo")
val chat5: BébéSiamois=new BébéSiamois("Elios")

val listeFelins=List(chat2,chat3,chat4,chat5)
```

And here is my problem how can I access to field name common at Chat, Siamois and BébéSiamois in the foreach ?

```
def createAListeOfSiamoisAndChild[T<:Siamois](xs:List[T]):Unit={
  xs.foreach(println(_))
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make it `val name: String`. In plain classes (i.e. not case class) field without `val` generates a `private` modifier. Case class do that as a part of overall syntax sugar, so another possibility is to make your classes `case`.

Also, you don't have to specify the type (`name: String`) when passing a value, usually Scala infers that.

Comment: It doesn't work, when I add val to it I can't access it no more

Comment: Make 2 small changes: `Siamois(val name:String)` and `foreach(c => println(c.name))` After that everything compiles and runs.

Comment: It doesn't work it seems it's because of the contraint [T <: Siamois] in the list there are Chat, Siamois and BébéSiamois objects

Comment: @uknys; I copied the code exactly as you posted it, pasted it into my IDE,  and made the 2 small changes I described. It compiled and ran with the expected output. If you have different results then perhaps the code posted in the question is not completely accurate.

Comment: I've tried println(_.name) instead of println(c=>c.name) it works thanks a lot

Comment: @uknys you can write `xs.foreach(println)` as well.